# Get model object with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I try to load an object model, in a List, with a org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.RestTemplate() and his method:

```
List<Document>  l = restTemplate.getForEntity("url", "class")
```

In other hand there is the webService implemented with springWeb like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/documents", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> list() {
    LOGGER.info(String.format("CALL : /rest/documents"));

    return new ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse>(new ServiceResponse(Code.OK, documentService.list()), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

How to extract the list from the responseEntity<> returned by restTemplate.getForEntity?

**The situation evolve.**
I did this:

```
ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> quote = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://apps.athena-software.fr/edocsol-ground-backend/rest/documents",
                ServiceResponse.class);

        List l = (List) quote.getBody().getResponse();
```

I have now a List with each key of Map is a field of the object "Document", i need to do a converter in order to get a List"Document" from the List"Map" you think or there is something that do it?

Answer (score 1):

The list is wrapped into a `ServiceResponse`, so you need to map to this class:

```
ServiceResponse serviceResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity("url", ServiceResponse.class);
List<Document> list = serviceResponse.getList(); // or whatever the method is called
```

Comment: This don't work with this exception, "Cannot cast from ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> to ServiceResponse"

Comment: Nice! So make `ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> entity = restTemplate.getForEntity("url", ResponseEntity.class);` and `entity.getBody()`.

Comment: Yes, the situation evolved, i edited the questions, thanks.